# Apache Camel How to pass SOAP message from JMS queue to CXF endpoint

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to create a Camel route that will:

1. Get JMS messages from a queue, the message body is a SOAP request.
2. Send the message to a cxf endpoint.
3. Put the response onto a response queue.

This is my code:

```
private void setupRequestRoute() {

    from("jms:queue:input")

    .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, simple("XXXXXX"))
    .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, simple("XXXXXX"))

    .log("Route headers : ${headers}")

    .to("cxf:bean:myEndpoint")
    .to("jms:queue:response")
        .end();
}
```

Endpoint configuration:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myServiceEndpoint"
                 address="http://localhost:8080/MyService/V2"
                 wsdlURL="schemas/MyService.wsdl"
                 xmlns:c="http://xxxx.xxxx/xxxxxxxx/XXX/MyService/V2">
 <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
   <ref bean="interceptor.out.soap.fault"/>
 </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
      <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
      <entry key="defaultBus" value="true" />
      <entry key="allowStreaming" value="false" />
  </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

I feel I've misunderstood something fundamental about camel works in this scenario. It appears to be the presence of the soap envelope that is causing this issue. I had presumed that camel would be able to take the raw soap message and convert it to the correct message format for the cxf endpoint.

Could someone explain to me how I can pass the SOAP request to the CXF endpoint?

```
2018-12-03 12:27:32,222 | ERROR | INPUT] | DefaultErrorHandler              | 43 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:xxxxxxxxxxxx-46588-1543829293785-1:21:1:1:1 
on ExchangeId: ID-xxxxxxxxxxxx-35264-1543835233229-2-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The PayLoad elements cannot fit with the message parts of the BindingOpera
tion. Please check the BindingOperation and PayLoadMessage.

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [jms://queue:input                                                             ] [        17]
[from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [setHeader7        ] [setHeader[operationName]                                                      ] [         0]
[from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [setHeader8        ] [setHeader[operationNamespace]                                                 ] [         0]
[from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [log6              ] [log                                                                           ] [        12]
[from.XS.to.xsb?dat] [to45              ] [cxf:bean:myEndpoint                                                           ] [         3]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
        Id                  ID-xxxxxxxxxxxx-35264-1543835233229-2-1
        ExchangePattern     InOut
        Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID:xxxxxxxxxxxx-46588-1543829293785-1:21:1:1:1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2,
 JMSDestination=queue://input, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:xxxxxxxxxxxx-46588-1543829293785-1:21:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=queue://response, JMSTimestamp=1543840052184, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, operationName=MyOperation, operationNamespace=MyOperationNameSpace}
        BodyType            String
        Body                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://xxxx.xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/V2" xmlns:v21="http://xxxx.xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxx/xxxxxx/V2">   
        <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecur
ity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-xxxx"><wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-ws
s-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">xxxx</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
xxxxx</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2018-12-03T12:27:32.183Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>   <soapenv:Body>      <v2:MyRequest>
...
...
</v2:MyRequest>   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
]

Stacktrace



Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The PayLoad elements cannot fit with the message parts of the BindingOperation. Please check the BindingOperation and PayLoadMessage.
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint$CamelCxfClientImpl.setParameters(CxfEndpoint.java:1189)[44:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:470)[57:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)[57:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:134)[44:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)[43:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)[46:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.4]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:555)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:515)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:485)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[154:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.17.RELEASE_1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify `PAYLOAD` data format, but according to the [docs](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxf-component.adoc#descriptions-of-the-dataformats) that is for `soap:body` processing.  Can you XPath out the body into the current exchange, or do you need all the WSE headers?

Or try one of the other data formats `MESSAGE` (called `RAW` in later versions I think?) or `CXF_MESSAGE` sound like they are closer to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I need the headers to verify the user against an internal web service. I managed to get it to work by specifying the dataFormat as RAW on the to() endpoint like this: `.to("cxf:bean:myEndpoint?dataFormat=RAW")` but leaving the dataFormat as PAYLOAD in the cxf bean. I also had to add `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` before the call to the cxf endpoint.